# Get past events of a contract without ABI using Web3?

Tags: web3js, events, abi

I'm building a simple explorer and I would like to list events emitted by contracts. Since I can't know the ABI of each contract, is it possible to get past events from a contract using Web3?
If I knew the ABI, I would do something like this:

```
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, address);

myContract.getPastEvents('allEvents', {
    filter: {...},
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, (error, events) => { console.log(events); })
.then((events) => {
    console.log(events) // same results as the optional callback above
});
```

But of course I can't instantiate a contract without its interface. I wonder how explorers such as Etherscan do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'web3.eth.getPastLogs({fromBlock: , address: }, (err, result))'

The result will contain Objects where the events are in the 'topics', but you can't decode the events without the ABI.

EDIT: topics is an array with the first element the event name and the following elements are the parameters